# Regular Expression that describes a language of {0,1} with no alternating 0's

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

Its mostly in the title, what I mean by alternating is that there is a single 1 or 0 between two occurrences of 0's. So no such occurrences of **0**1**0** or **0**0**0**.

I am trying to understand the theoretical nature of the question so I would prefer the answer in terms of just Concatenation, Union, and Closure (10, 1|0, and 10*).

Please note this is *NOT* a homework question I am just interested in the question, so please no patronizing comments to that affect.

Edit: changed the wording in the first paragraph from "between *the* occurrences" to "between *two* occurrences".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first important observation is that we can reduce the problem: if S is allowed and is `1` or ends with two ones, S concatenated with any allowed sequence remains allowed. So what makes a valid S?

1. `1` is explicitly in S, and any sequence of more than one `1` will always end in `11` and so is in S.
2. A `01` may only be followed by another `1`, as a `0` would give `010`. This ends in `11`, and so is a valid S.
3. A `00` may only be followed by `11`, as `0000`, `0001` and `0010` all have alternating zeros. This ends in `11`, and so is a valid S.

So that tells us any S matches `^(1|011|0011)*$`. But we're not done, as there are a few other sequences that are not valid for S but are themselves allowed sequences and so could be concatenated to an S.

- `0`
- `00`
- `01`
- `001`

`000` is not allowed, of course, and anything longer is either in S or is itself not allowed.

So the entire regex matching allowed sequences is:

```
^(1|011|0011)*(|0|00|01|001)$
```

That is zero or more S sequences, optionally followed by one of our allowed non-S sequences.

Comment: this is precisely what I was looking for, thank you for answering and taking the time to explain how you arrived at the answer.

Comment: Wonderful answer, very well thought out and articulated.